# Why is it skipping the else statement and not passing the correct image?

Tags: python, textblob

I've been playing around with the Streamlit module and wanted to make a very basic Sentiment analysis project but whenever my sentiment score is equal to 0 it skips the else statement, it's driving me mad.

Would appreciate some help thank you!

```
def get_polarity(phrase):

    sentiment_sentence = TextBlob(phrase)
    sentiment = sentiment_sentence.sentiment.polarity

    return sentiment


st.title('Sentiment Analysis in Python')

sentence = st.text_input('Enter a sentence: ')

result = get_polarity(sentence)

if result:

    if result > 0:
        st.image('positive.png')
        st.write('Your sentiment score: ', result)

    elif result < 0:
        st.image('negative.png')
        st.write('Your sentiment score: ', result)

    else:
        st.image('neutral.png')
        st.write('Your sentiment score: ', result)
```

Comment: `if result` will prevent it executing the lines below if `result` is 0

Comment: Yes, as @Kemp says...`0` is a [Falsy](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/) value in Python.  For `if result:`, `result` is `0` and therefore `false`, so nothing inside the `if` block will be executed.

Comment: So it's not skipping the `else:` statement, it's skipping the whole block.

Comment: Try out ```bool(0)``` and see, what it evaluates to. You could replace your ```if result``` with something like ```if result is not None```

Comment: Oh ok thank you guys ! I found it weird because it was working with if and the elif it just skipped the else. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As @Kemp has already stated in a comment, the statement `if result` is blocking the execution of everything in its block, if `result` is of value 0. Instead, you could try this:

```py
if result > 0:
    st.image('positive.png')
    st.write('Your sentiment score: ', result)

elif result < 0:
    st.image('negative.png')
    st.write('Your sentiment score: ', result)

else:
    st.image('neutral.png')
    st.write('Your sentiment score: ', result)
```

and drop the `if result:` statement completely, as TextBlob().sentiment.polarity will never return `None`.